# Recalculate Acumatica Taxes and Discounts programmatically

Tags: acumatica

We programmatically sync orders that come in on our website into Acumatica. It seems that tax and discount recalculation is not triggered automatically. Is there a way to trigger these calculations via the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Web Service Endpoint to include the RecalculateDiscounts action

Comment: To extend a web service endpoint, you can check out this blog post: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/extending-acumatica-web-service-endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, RecalculateDiscounts action does basically the same as defaulting mechanisms which should have been triggered upon insertion of document lines.
So, probably, it requires investifation why taxes (external or built-in?) were not caclulated automatically upon import